# YouTrack - Historical issue snapshots

Tags: youtrack, youtrack-api

The new YouTrack API is missing the old *Issue history* `/rest/issue/{issue}/history` [end-point](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/standalone/2020.6/Get-Issue-History.html) which our code heavily depends on. There's only the *Issue activities* `/api/issues/{issueID}/activities` [end-point](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/devportal/api-usecase-issue-history.html), which returns only delta differences between changes from [this never-ending list](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/devportal/api-entity-ActivityCategory.html) of diff/activity categories.

Is there some simple way to get a list of issue's historical snapshots, or do I actually have to parse all these activity categories and somehow merge them together to (re)implement this whole thing by myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/history` endpoint didn't provide a history snapshot either, but `/activity` does output much more data indeed. Yet, that's the way to do it — traverse through data and build a snapshot based on the provided timestamps.